# How to use callback functions in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using the PHP API of an application. From the documentation of the application, callback function ([https://www.digisigner.com/esignature-api/esignature-api-documentation](https://www.digisigner.com/esignature-api/esignature-api-documentation/))

```
If you need to be informed about the completion of the task 
request, you can register for an event notification. To accomplish 
this, a callback URL must be specified in your account settings.

The callback URL will be automatically called by the app when the 
task request has been completed, that is, when all the documents 
have been processed.
```

And the documentation goes on:

```
The app expects the response code 200 from your callback code, and 
the response text should be ‘EVENT_ACCEPTED’
```

I have registered my callback URL (for example: http://my_project/callback.php) for event notification

My question:

1. How my PHP callback function get the information that is sending by the app after the task has been completed?
2. How my PHP callback function return the code 200 and the response text?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If it exists it should return a 200. You will I assume get data passed in the $_POST, by it shoudl be documented somewhere in the API code

Comment: Don't confuse a callback URL with a [callback function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). API documentation just says that you can expose a script to receive a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your callback.php should be like next:

```
<?php
// here can be $_GET or $_POST, depend by API that call the callback
$parameters = $_REQUEST;

/*

Do what you need with callback parameters
I mean you need to log received data in some way
and return right response

*/

die('DIGISIGNER_EVENT_ACCEPTED');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what you think the API needs as a callback.

But as far as response code and text goes, it most likely expects header information. In your callback file, insert this at the beginning of the code, after <?php

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 200 EVENT_ACCEPTED");
```

I used the $_SERVER global cause it is safer that way. An alternate method is explicitly the HTTP version, for example:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 EVENT_ACCEPTED");
```